# Cypher get outgoing relationships of list of nodes limited to a amount

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some `:book`s. Books are idenifyed by an `ISBN`s and have `:similar` relationships to related books. Here is my cypher query to get similar books to the provided list of ISBNs:

```
MATCH (b:Book)-[:SIMILAR]-(c:Book) 
WHERE b.ISBN in $ISBNs
return b, c
```

However, I would like to limit the number of similar books per book to 5, without limiting the total books. In other words, I currently get 7 similar on one book, 6 on another, and 3 on one if I provide a certain list of ISBNs. I would like to limit that to 5 per book, so I get 5, 5, and 3. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to:

```
MATCH (b:Book)-[:SIMILAR]-(c:Book) 
WHERE b.ISBN in $ISBNs
RETURN {book:b, similars: collect(c)[..5]}
```

This query uses the [collect()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function to collects all the similar books into a list. It will return a projection with a `book` key that contains the main book and a `similars` key that contains a collection of similar books limited to 5 books.

Answer (score 1):

With APOC Procedures you can limit the number of match results per-row, rather than applying the limit to the total rows.

Take a look at this [knowledge base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/) for how to achieve this with `apoc.cypher.run()`.

If you can't use APOC Procedures, you can use Bruno's answer, which takes the limited slice of a collection.